# Oracle PLSQL 11g; Store large JSON object as CLOB (buffer too small at 122k chars)

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, clob

I have looked online and all I've found is people handling clobs and building JSON formatted text into CLOBs.
I'm building up a JSON object and then storing them as a clob which is then returned by a function, which works when the JSON object is small, I am generating 122k chars.
So here goes,
This is my JSON object:

```
jsonschemeresult json := json();
```

Which at the end of my PLSQL has something like this: (funds can repeat hence the 122k):

```
{
    "report_level": {
        "report_date": "15/03/2019"
    },
    "scheme_level":
 {
        "name": "A name",
        "id": "123123123",
        "funds": [{
            "fund_name": "Fund 1",
            "fund_value": 123123.12
        }, {
            "fund_name": "Fund 2",
            "fund_value": 987987.98
        }]
    }
}
```

I can get a console output using this, which is how I know its 122k in length:

jsonschemeresult.print;

And if the JSON is small I can get the CLOB to return using this:

```
v_final_clob := jsonschemeresult.to_char; 
RETURN v_final_clob;
```

I believe it's the to_char that is the restriction.

I've looked online and on here, and others use a loop and loop through the CLOB, I need to try and loop through the JSON object or something similar.

Kindly review and give feedback.

Comment: it's not entirely clear what your problem is. Why can't you change the function to return a CLOB?

Comment: you need to actually show us your code, keep it as a clob throughout and you'll be golden. also note that native json support in 12/18/19c of the database makes all of this much easier

Comment: the code I have at the minute is quiet large (1000 lines), and owned by the company. So i cant just copy and paste it. This is an example of how some of the JSON lines are built up: json_ext.put(jsonschemeresult, 'report_level.report_date', to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'));

Comment: It's been done this way so the PLSQL can format the JSON rather than having to hardcode and built the JSON syntax into the PLSQL manually. The function does return a CLOB, but the issue is that the JSON is built as a JSON object within the function, not as a CLOB, and then at the end of the function, the JSON is stored into a CLOB to be returned

Comment: Our Department is aware of 12c and I believe an upgrade is in the pipeline (at some point). But we've been having to manage with 11g for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, create a temporary lob, and use the JSON_AC procedure object_to_clob to convert the JSON object to a CLOB:

```
--use temporary LOB to hold the JSON
dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => v_out_json_clob, cache => TRUE);

--using the temporary LOB convert the JSON to a CLOB
utluser.json_ac.object_to_clob(p_self => jsonschemeresult, buf => v_out_json_clob);

RETURN v_out_json_clob;
```

One drawback, is you lose the 'pretty' JSON formatting in the returned CLOB, but syntactically, it works.